# Flex child element goes out of parent container element with overflow scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I get the `main-content` to shrink from the right rather than going behind the sidebar? Not sure flexbox is needed for what I'm trying to do but it's almost working..

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qJJeMr

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.main-content {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.main-content .content {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 720px;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 700px;
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar .side-menu-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  background: lightcyan;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="side-menu-bar"></div>
      <div class="side-content-panel"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">
      In main container, outside main content...

      <div class="content">
        This is the main content.
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not shrinking as you want, and overlapping its sibling element, because it has a fixed minimum width.

```
.main-content .content {
    background: lightgreen;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    min-width: 720px; <----- HERE
}
```

Comment: I don't want main-content to shrink, I want the child elements to fit in the boundary of main-content and push to the right, user has to scroll to see the elements if screen is too small. I asked the wrong question I've updated it

Answer (score 0):

The main content on the right is not shrinking since you have given a `min-width:720px;` for `.content`, Once you remove that, your issue will be fixed.